# Installing PostGIS on Mac OS

Tags: postgis, installation, macos

I am running PostgreSQL 9.0 on Mac OS 10.5. I've installed postgis-pg90-1.5.3-1-osx through "Stack Builder" but still don't see postgis in my list of databases when I open PgAdmin. When I open my Qgis 1.7, I can connect to my postgres database and display all tables with no spatial geometry. However, when I try to query a non-spatial table, I get the following message "Your database has no working PostGIS support".

---

Unfortunately, the link http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres is limited to "...Lion and Snow Leopard, 64bit only." I'm using Leopard (Mac OS 10.5). The link http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPackages provides two options. Both of these (http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) & (http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/204-postgis15-install-yum.html) point to Linux installations. So, I'm still stuck. I've downloaded PostGIS 1.5 using Application Stack Builder 3.0.0 from PostgreSQL 9.0. It installs, but does not run.

Answer (score 4):

I used this website to install the same version of PG you are using on my Mac.

http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres

It includes instructions for PostGIS installation.

This is another website with more options:

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPackages